# Error injecting: ch.fortysix.maven.plugin.postaman.MailSenderMojo

Tags: maven, postman

While running the postman plug in POM.  We have observed this error in particular system. But at the same time we are successfully executed the same POM file in other systems.

Tried this link but no luck:
[Required class is missing: org/codehaus/gmaven/mojo/GroovyMojo when tried to run to generate report and send an email in the Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935076/required-class-is-missing-org-codehaus-gmaven-mojo-groovymojo-when-tried-to-run)

[WARNING] Error injecting: ch.fortysix.maven.plugin.postaman.MailSenderMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type ch.fortysix.maven.plugin.postaman.MailSenderMojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed .m2 floder in the Users. After that update the maven project. It will take some time to create the new .m2 folder.

This time It won't fail.

**Note:** Don't delete any specific folders, Just delete the complete .m2 then only you can resolve it.